# Function for sorting struct array in C

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to create a function for sorting an array of struct. The problem is, I want user to chose by which element of struct sorting should be done:

I create following program to do the job.

```
void sort(Account reg[],int pNrOfAccounts,char member[]){
    Account tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < pNrOfAccounts; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < pNrOfAccounts - 1; j++) {
            if (strcmp(reg[j].member, reg[j+1].member)) > 0) {
                tmp = reg[j];
                reg [j] = reg[j+1];
                reg[j+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Parameter "member" is user provided, which matches one of the struct elements name. I assume if user input (parameter "member") is "name" then reg[j].member is same as reg[j].name.

But I got following error.

```
'Account' has no member named 'member'
```

Account structure:

```
typedef struct account{
    char name[WORDLENGTH];
    char surname[WORDLENGTH];
    int number;
    int balance;
}Account;
```

Please help me in finding what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "Hope you have understood my question!" - Which question?

Comment: That is about as clear an error message as a compiler is ever going to give you!

Comment: Its hard to say when we don't have the Account class. Could you post the code?

Comment: you are trying to call a member of struct called "member", but definition of Account has no field named "member". You can do `reg[j].name` `reg[j].surname` `reg[j].number` `reg[j].balance` Or you can do `member[j]`, since that's the other argument of your function. But `reg[j].member` makes no sense

Comment: Change `sort(Account reg[],int pNrOfAccounts,char member[])` to `sort(Account reg[],int pNrOfAccounts,size_t offset)` where `offset` is the offset of `name` or `surname`.  Then change code use `offset`, something like `strcmp((char*)reg[j] +offset, (char*)reg[j+1] +offset)`.  But this in not trivial for a learner.

Comment: Thank you chux! i think i will just write three seperate sorting functions for the diffrent members.

Comment: Rephrased the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues in your code.

1) You cannot access structure member like that.. compile will not replace member with the actual string value.

2) Your structure contains both number and strings. How can you use strcmp for both.

You can handle it like this:

```
    if (strcmp(reg[j].member, reg[j+1].member)) > 0) {

    //Change this to:

    if (my_compare(reg[j], reg[j+1], member)) > 0) {


    //***Write your custom compare function***

    int compare(Account a,Account b,char member[]){

    if (0==strcmp(member, name))
        return strcmp(a.name, b.name);

    //..........................................

    //for int:

    if (0==strcmp(member, number))
        return a.number - b.number;

    //***and so on....***
    .................................................
```

Answer (score 0):

`Account` does not have a field named `member`. There is not much more to say without seeing full compilable code, but the compiler for sure does not "see" `member` in your struct definition for `Account`.

Comment: The thing is i want the input char member[] to replace the text member in if (strcmp(reg[j].member, reg[j+1].member)) > 0)

Answer (score 0):

I dont't think what you want can be done in c as a function. You will have to write a preprocessor macro that generates the code with the proper name for the struct member. This means you are limited to compile time and can not dynamically choose the member via string at runtime. Maybe something like this helps.

```
/* just a structure so we have something with two members */
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

/** some macros that will generate the function code */
#define MEMBER(x,y) x.y
#define PRINT( T, member ) void print_##T##_##member( T f )\
{  fprintf(stdout, "%d\n",  MEMBER( f, member) ); }


/** create two functions, one with access to Foo.a and one to Foo.b **/
PRINT( Foo, a )
PRINT( Foo, b )

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.a = 1;
    foo.b = 2;

    /** call the function **/
    print_Foo_a( foo );
    print_Foo_b( foo );
}
```

See working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/791ba42eb3739e66).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define WORDLENGTH 64

typedef struct account{
    char name[WORDLENGTH];
    char surname[WORDLENGTH];
    int number;
    int balance;
} Account;

int cmp_s(const void *x, const void *y){
    return strcmp( (char*)x, (char*)y );
}
int cmp_i(const void *x, const void *y){
    int a = *(int *)x;
    int b = *(int *)y;
    return (a > b) - (a < b);
}

void sort(Account reg[], int pNrOfAccounts, char member[]){
    Account tmp;
    int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *);
    size_t offset;

    //To determine the comparison function and offset to a member by member name
    if(strcmp(member, "name")== 0){
        cmp = cmp_s;
        offset = offsetof(Account, name);
    } else if(strcmp(member, "surname")== 0){
        cmp = cmp_s;
        offset = offsetof(Account, surname);
    } else if(strcmp(member, "number")== 0){
        cmp = cmp_i;
        offset = offsetof(Account, number);
    } else if(strcmp(member, "balance")== 0){
        cmp = cmp_i;
        offset = offsetof(Account, balance);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pNrOfAccounts; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < pNrOfAccounts - 1; j++) {
            if (cmp((char*)&reg[j] + offset, (char*)&reg[j+1] + offset) > 0) {
                tmp = reg[j];
                reg [j] = reg[j+1];
                reg[j+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
//test code
int main(void) {
    Account reg[] = {
        { "Richard", "Feynman" , 55555, 11111 },
        { "Albert" , "Einstein", 99999, 88888 },
        { "Max"    , "Planck"  , 44444, 77777 },
    };
    int n = sizeof(reg)/sizeof(*reg);
    char *members[] = { "name", "surname", "number", "balance", NULL };
    char **member = members;

    while(*member){
        sort(reg, n, *member);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            printf("%s, %s, %d, %d\n", reg[i].name, reg[i].surname, reg[i].number, reg[i].balance);
        puts("");
        ++member;
    }
    return 0;
}
```